# Default activity not found Android Studio - repeating error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, manifest

I've just started having this issue today on a project that has been working for months, without changing the manifest at all I get this error when trying to run the app. My main activity is defined in the manifest as:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MenuActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I've tried all of the solutions I've found from previous questions to unfortunately no effect.

The weirdest part of this is if I hit "sync project with gradle files" 5-10 times one right after the other, it will start working for a few runs and then i'll need to repeat to fix the problem again. Anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your configuration as below **Edit Configurations**:

[image]

Then select your **Default Activity** as below **Launch Options**:

[image]